# Is it possible to run Spring Cloud Gateway on an external application server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive, application-server, spring-cloud-gateway

I want to create a war file of Spring Cloud Gateway Project (version 2.1.2.RELEASE) and deploy it on a container which supports reactive, is it possible? which application server is suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this is possible, but I wouldn't recommended it. If you package your application as a runnable jar it will ship with an embedded application server so it can run everywhere.